# How to Get List Attachment URL's using SharePoint Designer Workflow?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

How to Get List Attachment URL's using SharePoint Designer Workflow.

Answer (score 4):

Its possible if you are using SharePoint 2013. In SharePoint Designer 2013 you can call REST API to get the attachments by hitting their url.. Check the below site:

https://sergeluca.wordpress.com/2013/04/09/calling-the-sharepoint-2013-rest-api-from-a-sharepoint-designer-workflow/