# Send an email with attachments through a workflow

Tags: workflow, email, attachments

I have been looking for a solution to my issue, but I can't find anything.

The matter is the following:
- I set up a workflow to start manually to send an email to a specific distribution list, whenever an engineer wants to send a start of test for a vehicle (an item in the list).
- When starting the workflow, the engineer will fill out a form (parameters) and then start the workflow.

Is it possible to browse for an attachment when filling out the form, adding in the parameters, and then have it send it in the email through the workflow?
I am not able to add the attachment in the workflow. The attachments are in .pdf file and they are located in the engineers' desktop.

Not sure if I am making much sense, please let me know if you would like me to explain myself better.

Any help please?

Thank you

Comment: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/173888/how-to-get-list-attachment-urls-using-sharepoint-designer-workflow

Answer (score 0):

you'll have to include the attachment as a link to the document

[How to Get List Attachment URL's using SharePoint Designer Workflow?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/173888/how-to-get-list-attachment-urls-using-sharepoint-designer-workflow)